# My terminal freezes after running C program

Tags: c, cs50

**What am I trying to do?**

I am trying to solve the [recover](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/recover/) problem in the CS50, it goes like this...

You are given a somehow corrupted file, how? Well the file is supposed to be multiple JPG files instead of a single big one. You are tasked to separate said file into multiple JPGs, to do this you have to loop through the bytes in the original file and find this `0xff 0xd8 0xff` and a number that ranges between `0xe0` and `0xef`... what do those numbers mean? well they indicate the start of a JPG and so you have to create and close files depending on that info...

The problem is pretty long so press [this](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/recover/) to know more.

**What have I done?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//create new data type BYTE
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //variables
    int counter = 0;
    char name[8];
    //create new array of BYTES, it is 512 because as you can see later I am reading the input file in 512 byte chunks
    BYTE buffer[512];
    int bytes = 512;
    //output image
    FILE* img;
    //input image
    FILE* f;

    //checks if the arguments passed are wrong
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover <file>");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //opens the file passed in the arguments 
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    //checks if file is null
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("bruh");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //loop till you reach zero
    //also read in 512 bytes chunks from the input file and store to buffer
    while (fread(buffer, bytes, 1, f))
    {
        //checks if this is a jpg, and if it is checks if it is the first one
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0 && counter == 0)
        {
            //assigns new value to name
            sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            //creates new file with the name we've just created
            img = fopen(name, "w");
            //write to that file
            fwrite(buffer, bytes, 1, img);
            //increment number of files by 1
            counter++;
        }
        //checks if it encoutered another jpg, if it did it will close the last created file and create a new one
        else if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            //closes last file
            fclose(img);
            //assigns new value to name depending on how many images were printed
            sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            //creates new file with the name we've just created
            img = fopen(name, "w");
            //writes to that file
            fwrite(buffer, bytes, 1, img);
            //increment number of files by one
            counter++;
        }

        //if no jpgs are encountered, continue to write to the last file
        else
        {
            fwrite(buffer, bytes, 1, img);
        }
    }
    //close opened files
    fclose(f);
    fclose(img);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you thought I dumped a chunk of code on you without telling you what I did, I've commented out everybit.

**What has gone wrong?**

Well based on the title of the post, when I run the program and pass some arguments... the terminal simply freezes, nothing appears... no errors what so ever.

if you want to replicate this problem:

- run `wget https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/psets/4/recover/recover.zip`
  in your terminal and unzip the file...
- then type `make recover` to compile (if that doesn't work just use
  clang normally)
- finally type `./recover card.raw` to run program... it is supposed to produce about 50 files but again it doesn't

Comment: Why not use a debugger to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: @BinyaminR because `debug50` does the same thing, it freezes and I have to start a new terminal window again

Comment: Don't know what debug50 is but a debugger won't just freeze. It allows you to break into the running program to see where it is "stuck".

Comment: And how about simple printf? Seems like there is alot more debugging you haven't done yet.

Comment: @kaylum I am pretty sure that I did that. But the debugger won't even start

Comment: You can always break at main and step one line at a time.

Comment: @kaylum like I've said the debugger doesn't start no matter where I break, the program doesn't run... and so it doesn't break anywhere (it compiles just fine though)

Comment: I don't quite believe that. Either you are not using the tool right or it is broken and nothing to do with your program. Any decent debugger will allow you to break even before the program starts and your program would not be able to affect that. And how about printf?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the terminal gets stuck: that the program does not terminate, Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z doesn't work? If either of the last two happens, it is extremely unusual. However, on recreating your program, I get a SIGSEGV, as is to be expected by @prog-fh's answer below. Further, debugging with `gdb` shows where the segmentation fault occurs, again as expected.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu8mhB5z1iU here is it, and no control c or z dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last `else` could occur even if no suitable header has been
found before; in this case, your `img` file may not have been
opened before beeing used.

You have to initialise correctly in the first place

```
FILE* img=NULL; // you forgot this initialisation
```

then, in the last `else`, you can test if the file is actually open.

```
if(img!=NULL) // you forgot this test
{
  fwrite(buffer, bytes, 1, img);
}
```

On my computer, your initial program just stops on segmentation
violation because, *by chance*, even if not explicitly initialised,
`img` happens to be `NULL`.

I guess that if `fwrite()` uses an uninitialised `img` pointing
to arbitrary but reachable memory, it could *by chance* interpret
this undefined/uninitialised `FILE` as being related to standard
I/O; then sending arbitrary bytes on standard I/O can freeze the
terminal...
But nothing is less certain...